# How to use bootstrap datepicker input field in angular2

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I have followed the undermentioned steps and I have been able to achieve up to the following image.

1. Install nodejs of version 6.9.1. It comes with npm 3.10.8
2. Then I followed the following [installation steps](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).
3. Now when I try to use `<ngb-datepicker></ngb-datepicker>` I am able to see this type of screen.
   [image: ngb-datepicker]

But I am not able to understand how to use `input[ngbDatepicker]`

I tried `<input ngbDatepicker />` but only a text box appears. When I focus it, it is not showing the date picker.

Here is the [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker) which I am using.

Comment: Have you added `bootstrap` css in your HTML ?

Comment: Yes. After adding this just design got change. But nothing extra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working a lot and got the suggestion from [ranakrunal9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4395301/ranakrunal9). I have reached in this following code base. It is working fine in all aspect (But still only one issue I have that, the datepicker is not being closed if I click outside of the datepicker) Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3OM2pB8EUAS93wZQxy0E?p=preview)

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {NgbModule, NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
    BrowserModule,
    NgbDateParserFormatter
  ],
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'template.html'
})
export class App {


}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, 
    NgbModule.forRoot()],
  providers : [
    {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: forwardRef(() => CustomDateParserFormatter)}
  ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}



export class CustomDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
    if (value) {
      const dateParts = value.trim().split('/');
      /*
     Put your logic for parsing
      */
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    return date ?
        date.day+'/'+date.month+'/'+date.year :
        '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find out how to close it on blur? I tried binding (blur) to execute d.close(). The problem is, "using the calendar" counts as blur too and so the calendar closes before I get to pick a date.

Comment: Yes, Same issue I also found, did not solved it yet. If you can place a new question and link it here also I think it will be helpful. Please also create a plunker.

Answer (score 6):

To display datepicker on focus you can use `focus` event of input by using [template reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars) as below :

```
<input ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (focus)="d.open()">
```

Or you can add trigger `toggle` event of datepicker on button click as per `Datepicker in a popup` example of [Datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker)

```
// Component
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html'
})
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup {
  model;
}

// HTML
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
  <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" >
    <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Date format needs an NgbDateParserFormatter per https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker

Comment: Still I am not able to use it. Very minimal documentation. Please help.

Comment: I think , for date formatting you have to create your custom Formatter by extending `NgbDateParserFormatter` as per https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/ngb-date-parser-formatter.ts and need add it as provider in your component like `{provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: CustomDateParserFormatter}` as example `Internationalization of datepickers` on page https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker